# IIS Worker Process and RAM question (w3wp.exe)

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008

In my vds server (windows server 2008) some asp.net websites using iis worker and these use also 50 mb ram.
Sometimes this is increase to 250 mb.
Is it normal?

Comment: Vote to close as subjective, the amount of ram usage is entirely dependent on the application itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think I fix my problem. Debug mode was true and I change it false. Now it's using 20mb.